# How to get the image width from ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseData()

Tags: jmeter

I am writing BeanShell Sampler code in Jmeter for getting image width, which we get from a previous jmeter http request.

```
byte[] samplerdata=ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseData();
```

How can I store the image from the above code, and get the image width and height?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is using [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) package.

Sample code:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

byte[] samplerData=ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseData();

InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(samplerData));
String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(in);

BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
int width = image.getWidth();
int height = image.getHeight();
String extension = mimeType.split("/")[1];
File file = new File("image." + extension);
ImageIO.write(image, extension, file);

return "Written image: " + file.getAbsolutePath() + "; width: " + width + "; height: " + height;
```

It isn't very recommended to use Beanshell for scripting as it has some known performance problems and it may ruin your test in case of severe load.

According to [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) it is better to use JSR223 Test Elements and "groovy" as a language.

See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) guide for groovy scripting engine installation instructions, scripting best patterns and different scripting engines benchmark.

Don't worry regarding compatibility as valid Java or Beanshell code will be valid Groovy code in 99% of cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot, This is working as per my requirement. Now i am able to get the width and height